# regexp for arithmetic operation

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to create a regexp to validate an input in HTML, the arithmetic expression which user can enter should be limited to as below

Example

- (5>3&8<6)||(98=9||34<40)
- (5>=3||8<=6)&(98=9||34<40)

The expression can be (number[<,>,<=,>=,=]number[logical and / logical or ] number ....)
I am using the regexp for input type as `pattern="([0-9]*|>|<|=|&)|&|||+"`.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the `|` part of the input, or do you mean it can be this OR that?

Comment: It is the logical or expression which is represented as '||'

Comment: So you want to match it literally, like in my demo?

Comment: why didn't you use conditional operator for it rather than regexp?

Comment: As the user can enter expression like this which is not only limited to 2 comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this (see [demo](http://regex101.com/r/qQ6kV6)):

```
\(\d+(?:=|[<>]=?)\d+(?:&|\|\|)\d+(?:=|[<>]=?)\d+\)(?:&|\|\|)\(\d+(?:=|[<>]=?)\d+(&|\|\|)\d+(?:=|[<>]=?)\d+\)
```

- At the moment, in the parentheses we are allowing `<` and `>`
- Let me know if you need to add or remove any operators. :)

Comment: I have modified the question with more examples, hope its clear. In parenthesis i want to check for <,>,<=,>=,=.

Comment: Thanks, revised the regex and demo. I have all of them except the `+` and `-` because I don't understand where they can occur. Can you give me an example?

Comment: Thanks. I am using in one of my project where user is allowed to enter expression and the same is being sent to server.

Comment: Yes, but please show me an actual example with `+` or  `-` because I don't understand where to put it in the regex. I need to see an example. Thanks!!!

Comment: Do you mean that anywhere in the expression, you can have any of those: ||,&,+,-,=,<,>,<=,>= ?

Comment: One second, let me have a look

Comment: The expression can be (number[<,>,<=,>=,=]number[logical and / logical or ] number ....)